# Does Hamiltonian Monte Carlo explore the target distribution uniformly?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I am trying to incorporate HMC into an algorithm that requires me to generate samples that are uniformly distributed in the distribution being sampled. Ie, the samples are not necessarily uniformly distributed themselves, but they are uniformly distributed **according to** the distribution being sampled.

My initial thought was that as long as I am using some variant of HMC that generates ergodic chains (such as [No U Turn Sampling](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1111.4246.pdf)), the above condition would be satisfied. However, reading [Skilling](https://www.mdpi.com/2504-3900/33/1/19), he states that the Hamiltonian `trajectory explores non-uniformly'.

Is this the case for all variants of HMC? If so, is there a way to measure how it does explore the distribution?